# How to plot a 3d surface?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I want to plot a 3d surface, which has a paramter form:

```
x = (-2 * (s^2 - t)^  3)

y = log(t*(t-2*s^2)+2*s^2)

z = 1/(s^2-t)
```

where `s`, `t` are parameter . and I use `plt_surface`, but it does not work . I don't know what is going on, could you help me ?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import  math
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

s,t=symbols('s,t')
x=Function('x')(s,t)
z=Function('z')(s,t)
y=Function('y')(s,t)
figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
t1= np.linspace(1,100,200)
s1 = np.linspace(1,100,200)
s,t=np.meshgrid(s1,t1)
x = (-2 * (s*s - t)**3)
y = log(t*(t-2*s*s)+2*s*s)
z = 1/(s*s-t)
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,cmap='rainbow')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_title('f')
plt.show()
```

after run , it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):


     File "C:/Users/apple/Desktop/pywork/mining/rep.py", line 19, in <module>
        y = log(s)
      File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 458, in __new__
        result = super(Function, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 277, in __new__
        evaluated = cls.eval(*args)
      File "C:\Users\apple\Desktop\pywork\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\exponential.py", line 577, in eval
        coeff = arg.as_coefficient(S.ImaginaryUnit)
    AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_coefficient'

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Write your code not in an image.

Comment: @AbdelAziz AbdelLatef  Now I have writen my code

Comment: The errors are found at least in 2 places, first, in `y = ...` error of invalid value in log(). And in `z=...`, error of divided by zero. Maybe, the domain values of `t1` and `s1` are not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get some result from your code, you need valid input data. In this case, the domain of `t1` is not appropriate, and causes errors in computation of `y` and `z`. Here is the modified code that the domain of `t1` is changed in such a way that the original code can run and produce some plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#import math
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
from sympy import symbols, Function

s,t = symbols('s,t')
x = Function('x')(s,t)
z = Function('z')(s,t)
y = Function('y')(s,t)

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

# experiment with various range of data
t1 = np.linspace(-1,-100,200)  #...to enable computation
s1 = np.linspace(1,100,200)
s,t = np.meshgrid(s1,t1)
x = -2*(s*s - t)**3

y = np.log(t*(t-2*s*s)+2*s*s)  # need np.
z = 1/(s*s-t)  

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,cmap='rainbow')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_title('f')
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]